# Formatting kendo numeric text box

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo numeric box in grid. Only numbers are allowed in it. No decimal places and no comma separators. I tried in different ways but did not succeeded. Any idea ... Please help me...

In data source fields i given like this

```
seq_no  : {type: "number",validation: {min: 1,max: 32767}}
```

In column of grid

```
{ field: "seq_no", width: "50px", title: "Sequence Number", type:"number"}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`format`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnsformat-string) with value `{0:n0}`:

```
{ field: "seq_no", width: "50px", title: "Sequence Number", type:"number", format: "{0:n0}" }
```

Answer (score 16):

Above mentioned answer is working, 
but it allows to enter  decimal points. But this solution I implemented not allow a user to enter decimal points in text box

```
{ field: "seq_no",width: "10px", title: "Sequence Number",
    editor: function(container, options) { 
            $('<input  maxlength="5"  name="' + options.field + '"/>')
             .appendTo(container)
             .kendoNumericTextBox({
               min:0,
               max: 32767,
               format:"#",
               decimals:0
             })
        }
}
```

Comment: Also if you use angularjs, don't forget to wrap in quotes twice like: k-format="'#'"

Answer (score 5):

For some reason:

```
format: "{0:n0}"
```

does not always get rid of the seperator. But I find that:

```
format: "{0:#.##}"
```

works nicely on the model field.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
format: "{#.##}"
```

This one removes grouping together with decimal separator